# Vue.JS app not working on IIS (url rewriting?)

Tags: vue.js, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I saw lot of posts about vue.js on IIS but my project is not working.

1. Vue.JS Application with router :

```
      const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '/Applications',
        name: 'Applications',
        component: Applications
      }
    ]
    
    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes
    })
```

2. Web server :

- IIS 10
- Url Rewrite 2 :

  - [Url rewrite configuration import from web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQuE8.png)
  - Url rewrite is working (tried this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)
- web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

3. Result :

- Blank page
- Inspector console errors (missing my application node into url)

  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  - GET http://localhost/css/app.63040a86.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I already tried all things found but it's not working, can you help me please ?

Comment: Your project is not working, do you get any error messages? can it work normally on local system? when you use failed request tracking, what is the error message in the frt file?

Comment: it worked when i added :
- "vue.config.js" file with :
    module.exports = {
        publicPath: '/ApplicationName/'
    }